# Need a date of a last week in Freemarker

Tags: date, freemarker

I need to get the date of last week from current date to run a DB query.

I have:

```
<#assign dateToday = .now?string("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'+00:00'") />
```

Which prints "2015-03-17T23:56:45+00:00"

I need to get "2015-03-**10**T23:56:45+00:00"

Comment: Compute date outside of FreeMarker template and put it into model.

Comment: Templates aren't for calculation, they are for displaying already calculated data. Thar's the whole point of them really, that you can have these separated concerns. So even if there's a hack below for this, avoid doing things like this.

Comment: @ddekany - It isn't a hack, sev simply used the available methods in FTL.

Comment: @Chunkz: FreeMarker has some extra power over some other template languages because purely presentation related tasks aren't aways simple. This however unavoidably makes the language complete enough so that some will feel encouraged to solve things in the templates that don't belong there. Try to do that with a Mustache templates for example. It won't let you. OTOH the power won't be there for legitimate uses either. You get the point, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the date to milliseconds, then subtract 1 week, like so:

```
<#assign dateToday = .now?long />
<#assign lastWeek = dateToday - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) />

${dateToday?number_to_datetime?iso_utc}<br>
${lastWeek?number_to_datetime?iso_utc}
```

Output:

```
2015-03-18T18:31:49Z
2015-03-11T18:31:49Z
```

Sources:

- [?number_to_datetime](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_builtin_numToDate)
- [?long](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_builtin_numType)